# How to Invoke The exe from Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a windows service which invokes the Exe. This exe is basically subscribing to MQTT broker for a particular topic, and writing the results to a file upon receiving the publish from the broker. The problem I am facing is, exe is not performing its tasks until the service is being opened. When I close my service exe starts performing the functions. Code which I used to invoke exe is as below :

```
private void callExe(String param)
{
    Process MqttProcess = new Process();

    MqttProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\ServiceManager\Mqtt\Mqtt\bin\Debug\Mqtt.exe";
    MqttProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = param;
    MqttProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    MqttProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    MqttProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    MqttProcess.Start();
    MqttProcess.CloseMainWindow();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your problem? Does the process not start? Do you get an error? Why are you closing the process right after it starts?

Comment: it would suggest that its throwing you a window you arent expecting, such as say the MS office "Enter your initals/details" window ..  best way to find out is to use the runas command and run it as your service account.

Comment: @pmf Service is starting and and invoking my exe. But the exe operations (The things which my exe is performing) are happening only after i close my main window.

Comment: Why are you calling "CloseMainWindow" on the other process? Is this process a gui application? If it is, consider changing that, because this is not going to work reliably.